# Confusion over Go's http2 implementation

Tags: http, go, http2

I run tons of traffic over SSL. I was thinking of speeding up these calls by using a http2 client. However, I'm hesitant to do so because it feels like i have less control on how it behaves.

Here is a production client using Go's basic net/http

```
ClientHTTP := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   timeout * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 1 * time.Minute,
        }).Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: timeout * time.Second,
        MaxIdleConns:        3000,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 3000,
        IdleConnTimeout:     60 * time.Second,
    },
    Timeout: timeout * time.Second,
}
```

As far as I can tell I have way less control on the transport.

```
ClientHTTP2 := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http2.Transport{
        AllowHTTP: true,
    },
    Timeout: timeout * time.Second,
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Is http2 production ready? I understand that http2 uses a single TCP connection and therefore things likes pools go away. Yet it somehow feels incomplete. Will these behave the same way as the production client? Is there a better way to implement `ClientHTTP2` and lastly, `AllowHTTP` doesn't seem to do anything. In the case where there might be an http call I thought I'd be able to able it safely, but instead it errors out.

Comment: Try to dig into this issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14008

Comment: `AllowHTTP` only enables HTTP2 over plain TCP (as opposed to TCP+TLS).

Comment: @majidarif, thanks for showing me that issue, I hadn't come across it yet

Comment: @peter ohh that makes sense?

Comment: AllowHTTP isn't useful in general because you never know what proxies might do to the traffic, but in some cases it's useful. grpc can be configured to run without TLS, for example.

Comment: @Peter yeah I learned that the hard way lol, trial by fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http.Transport` supports HTTP2, however you have to configure the more modern DialContext, not Dial (which is deprecated):

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net"
        "net/http"
        "net/http/httputil"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        c := &http.Client{
                Transport: &http.Transport{
                        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
                        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{ // use DialContext here
                                Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
                                KeepAlive: 1 * time.Minute,
                        }).DialContext,
                        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
                        MaxIdleConns:        3000,
                        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 3000,
                        IdleConnTimeout:     60 * time.Second,
                },
                Timeout: 1 * time.Second,
        }
        res, _ := c.Get("https://http2.akamai.com/")
        b, _ := httputil.DumpResponse(res, false)
        fmt.Println(string(b))
}

// HTTP/2.0 200 OK
// Content-Length: 11928
// Accept-Ch: DPR, Width, Viewport-Width, Downlink, Save-Data
// Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
// ...
```

The only reason to use http2.Transport is to skip the initial connection upgrade (aka. prior knowledge). If that is not a concern, stick to the standard client and transport.

Comment: Will this increase the speed of the overall request. I know from the few tests I've run and numerous articles, https2 + TLS, is faster then http + TLS. Since I'm making millions of SSL GET and POST requests a day I'm hoping to reduce the latency created by the handshake and reduce overall cpu usage.. As a side note plus 1 for Dial Context, I had no idea Dial was depricated

Comment: Measure it. I can't possibly tell you what switching to HTTP/2 does for you in terms of performance. It depends.

Comment: oh I have measured, which is why I want to use HTTP/2. My confusion is whether or not http2 is ready for production in Go and whether or not my posted example is sufficient, correct, and fully feature like its time tested sibling http.Transport

Comment: It is ready for production. Anything in the standard library in a stable version of Go is production-ready, unless the documentation explicitly states otherwise.

Comment: @Adrian to your point the only place I see http2 is in `golang.org/x/net/http2`, which places it outside of the standard lib

Comment: It's supported transparently by `net/http`.